# Enable sbt plugin in IntelliJ IDEA 14

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am trying to use the [SBT dotenv plugin](https://github.com/mefellows/sbt-dotenv) with IntelliJ IDEA 14. I have only the Scala plugin installed (it seems SBT plugin is not there anymore). The IDEA project is imported from `build.sbt`.

I added the code from the SBT dotenv Readme to my `project/plugins.sbt`. I also added `project/build.properties` to specify SBT version 0.13.6.

When I run sbt console in my terminal it properly loads my .env file and I can access the ENV vars with `sys.get("NAME")`. However in IDEA, it will not load the vars. I test with adding `sys.get("NAME")` to one of my tests and run it. I tried restarting IDEA but it does not help. Also tried adding `project/.env` in addition to `.env` but it did not help.

Comment: Scala plugin for IntelliJ 14 supports SBT out of the box. You no need install any other plugins.

Comment: Yes well, this plugin does not seem to work out-of-the-box. Hence my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the sources of the dotenv plugin it does something it calls `DirtyEnvironmentHack.setEnv` which probably just works in a shell because it is a hack. I would guess this explains the environment isn't changed when loaded in IntelliJ.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think it "probably just works in a shell because it is a hack"? My guess was that IntelliJ isn't loading the auto plugins for some reason...

Comment: To be more specific, the code runs fine from IntelliJ if I call it explicitly from my app. So the problem is that IntelliJ isn't loading the auto plugin. It has nothing to do with the shell.

Comment: Or that the plugin runs fine but that the tests aren't run inside the same process or a child process in the same way that happens when you run it standalone. I'm pretty sure autoplugins work fine inside IntelliJ (or our project wouldn't work at all)